# Is there a readv / writev equivalent that works on char * bufs instead of file descriptors?

Tags: c

Is there a readv / writev equivalent that works on char * bufs instead of file descriptors?

For example, if I had an array of char * buf[] and I wanted to copy all of it into one char buf *.

Comment: that requires for loops, looking to use vector io with struct iovec.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? You're looking to concatenate the strings, or write them into null-separated array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (i=0; i<cnt; dest+=iov[i++].iov_len)
    memcpy(dest, iov[i].iov_base, iov[i].iov_len);
```

C is not a language full of library functions for trivial single-statement-body for loops.

Comment: I know was just hoping there was.

Comment: The reason `readv` and `writev` exist as functions is that they serve a purpose you can't do with a loop: they submit the combined read or write as a single request on the underlying fd (i.e. a single syscall) with atomicity (for pipes), blocking, and (perhaps most importantly) performance properties that couldn't be obtained by splitting it up into multiple `read` or `write` calls. For a `memcpy`, which happens entirely in userspace, there's no benefit to putting the combined operation in a library function except convenience.